# How to download content from URL using Jsoup and Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this code which extracts all links from an URL using JSOUP. I need to put all the content from these links into a txt. How can I do this using Java? +strong text

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc, content;
    try {


        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://fmi.unibuc.ro/ro").get();
        System.out.print(doc);

        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {

            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: To fetch the content of nested links you can do  `Jsoup.connect(<link>).get()` inside for loop

Comment: Inside connect must be String and link is not. Or maybe I don't get it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the URL from the links like this:

```
for (Element link : links) 
    System.out.println(Jsoup.connect(link.baseUri()).get());
```

It will print the content of all links on the console.

Comment: Cool, remember to approve the answer 

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
for (Element link : links) {
    System.out.println(Jsoup.connect(link.absUrl("href")).get());
}
```